# The efficiency dropps when integrate the CascadeClassifier in multithread

Tags: android, multithreading, opencv, java-native-interface

I want to detecteye on Anroid with OpenCV CascadeClassifier function.Then I integrate the CascadeClassifier into the Jni code.(I use two CascadeClassifiers which load haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml and haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml respectively) The program runs in phone(core of phone is Kinrin 950)and the process time of detecting eyes is  about 40-50ms. For improving the efficiency, I put the CascadeClassifiers into the subthread respectively.(I use pthread and semaphore in Jni). However, the process time extend to 60-70ms. How puzzled!
And I write some program using the same construction to test the efficiency of multithread. The process time of these program  decrease because of multi thread!
Then,I put other OpenCV function using tbb into multithread. The process time doesn't decrease. I suspect using tbb in multithread causes some conflict.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: probably CascadeClassifier uses multithreading  (block-parallelism) internally already.

Comment: detectMultiscale: 
The function is parallelized with the TBB library. http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/objdetect/CascadeClassifier.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How can I put the CascadeClassifier in subthread? Can I solve this problem, if rewriting subthread with TBB library. Please give some advice, my friend!